# Change theme settings from a module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have run into a brick wall with this one, I want to create a module to modify the default custom theme settings.  This way the user only sees certain settings for the theme that are set in the theme-settings.php so when they change the theme that theme settings are pulled in.  Is their a function to do this?

Cheers

Comment: this question is not very clear

Comment: in a nutshell I want to know whats the function or command to pull a theme settings into a module.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91067/how-to-set-theme-setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, There is a function called [theme_get_setting](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7) which should work for you. There is also a function [theme_system_settings_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/theme_system_settings_form/7)  that would return the form to collect the theme settings. Other theme functions can be found on the [Drupal Theme System Page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/group/themeable/7)

Note that theme_system_settings_form is not a hook, you should use it like this render the form:

```
$form = theme_system_settings_form();
/*Edit form here if needed*/
return $form;
```

You can add the above code to your hook_settings in your module.

Here is a [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/211015) on the issue theme_system_settings_form solves, You can learn alot about the function by going through this. Checkout comment 2 and 3 especially

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: So I could use something like:'function my_module_theme_system_settings_form($variables {$form = array(); return drupal_render_children($variables['form']); }'  To pull in the current theme settings?